# Why doesn’t this key remapping work in several GNOME applications?

Tags: wayland, remapping

I’d like to remap <kbd>]</kbd> to <kbd>Delete</kbd>. I’ve tried setting this in an XKB layout:

```
key <AD12> { [ Delete ] };
```

This works in Firefox, GNOME Terminal, and LibreOffice. However, nothing happens when I press <kbd>]</kbd> in Files, Calculator, and gedit. What’s going on?